# Duo generic SAML Service Provider with AWS Cognito user pool integration failing

Tags: amazon-web-services, single-sign-on, amazon-cognito, saml

I would like to setup DUO "Generic SAML Service Provider - Single Sign-On" application that should be integrated with AWS Cognito user pool.

My web application is running on AWS and the login flow should look like this:
Web app should redirect to DUO login page, check if DUO user is authorized to use the application and if yes, it should redirect back to application and have this user looged in.

I have this setup working with OKTA application without issues and I would like to have the same setup, but using DUO instead of OKTA.

After opening my web application URL, I get error: "An error was encountered with the requested page." and status code 400.
Before, when using OKTA instead of DUO and similar setup, it redirected me to OKTA login page.

Only relevant tutorial I was able to find was in the comment section in this cisco forum, where they try to achieve AWS ALB + Cognito + SAML: https://community.cisco.com/t5/protecting-applications/duo-as-mfa-idp-in-aws-alb/m-p/4885045

The similar setup that is in the comments is not working for me and they are not mentioning the fact that to create the SAML application, I need to create Single Sign-On Authentication Source first and it requires additional inputs.

My configuration is:

- Cognito User pool with SAML identity provider and app client, Cognito domain and signing certificate. App client is connected to identity provider and has following setup:

  - OAuth grant types: Authorization code grant, OpenID
  - Connect scopes: email, openid, profile
- Duo Single Sign-on authentication Source with following required inputs:

  - Entity ID: urn:amazon:cognito:sp:COGNITO-ID
  - Single Sign-On URL: https://CUSTOM-VALUE.us-east-2.amazoncognito.com/saml2/idpresponse
  - Existing Certificate: downloaded from Cognito
- Duo generic SAML Service Provider with following required inputs:

  - Entity ID: urn:amazon:cognito:sp:COGNITO-ID
  - Assertion Consumer Service (ACS) URL: https://CUSTOM-VALUE.us-east-2.amazoncognito.com/saml2/idpresponse
  - NameID format: urn:oasis:names:tx:SAML:1.1:nameid-format-unspecified
  - NameID attribute: <Email Address>
  - Signrature algorith: SHA256
  - Signing options: Sign respose and Sign assetion
  - Permitted groups: correctly selected group with me as user in it

Cognito identity provider "Metadata document endpoint URL" set to entity id of DUO SAML service provider: https://sso-ID.sso.duosecurity.com/saml2/sp/ANOTHER-id/metadata

So my questions is: Am i putting the correct values to input fields?
For OKTA, there was no need to setup "Single Sign-on authentication Source", put certificate and so, that my be the reason for my confusion.
I put some same values into DUO Sing-on authentication source and also DUO generic SAML Service Provider, and  Im not sure if that is correct.